# How to get firebase ios readable crash logs

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have been setting my app to use firebase as crashlytic with instructions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios.
When I got to the part "Upload symbol files" I added the file and script, but the script can't find `"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym` because this folder does not exist.

I have this pods installed

- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- pod 'Fabric'
- pod 'Crashlytics'

but somehow I'm missing that file. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

I am getting errors but they are not symbolicated.

I even found upload-symbols file in Fabric pods at "${PODS_ROOT}"/Fabric/upload-symbols, but then I get an error:

> error: missing required flag a/api-key

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking for `upload-symbols` binary needed to upload symbols to Firebase (Firebase is just the new name of Fabric Crashlytics), so you need to have the binary either from Pods or by installing the app.

You can download and install Fabric app from the following link: https://www.fabric.io/downloads/apple

Comment: Why do I need this?
I get the crashes on firebase console, they are just unreadable.

Comment: I added the why to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question as it should be, that was just one of ways that I tried to fix the error after I found that file